# Unity 5: Error when everything is okay(Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, unity

i'm getting this error when the collider colides with something:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

It's referencing to the gamecont.Death(); from this script:
[image: obstacle collider script]

and the death method is on this one:

[image: death script]

Comment: Please post code in as text.  Images like this can be too small to read on some screens.  An guide to the code formatting option can found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: I could already fix the problem!

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed:

gameCont = GetComponent();

to:

gameCont = GameObject.FindObjectOfType();

and worked!

Comment: Quick link to [FindObjectOfType](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) docs

Comment: Great help for everybody Matt!

Answer (score 0):

If gamecont is null, then probably the assignment from GetComponent failed which means either the component is not attached to the same GameObject as the one using the ObstacleMove script, or that the instance of GameController is disabled (see the component's check box).

Comment: The GameController script is on the main camera and it's enabled, and the ObstacleMove it's on each obstacle. When i create a game object variable and simply put the main camera OBJ in the obstacle prefab to get the gamecontroller script, the prefab doesn't "save" this, and delete this obj added to it.